# Foundation Menu Alignment Centering Issues

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm currently making a website using Zurb Foundation. (See pictures further down)

The way I've layed out my navigation is using the foundation grid as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">


<!-- Navigation -->

  <nav class="top-bar">
    <div class="five columns">
    <div class="one columns"></div>
        <div class="five columns menu-elements rightalign">
        <a href="about.html">About</a>
        </div>
        <div class="one columns">
        <div class="split"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="five columns menu-elements rightalign">
        <a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="two columns logo">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
        </div>
    <div class="five columns">
        <div class="five columns menu-elements leftalign">
        <a href="services.html">Services</a>
        </div>
        <div class="one columns">
        <div class="split"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="five columns menu-elements leftalign">
        <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </div>
        <div class="one columns"></div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.top-bar { font-family: 'bebas_neueregular'; display: flex; text-align:center; margin-bottom:0px;
.menu-elements{ color: white; display: block; font-size: 32px; font-weight: normal; height: 45px; ; margin: 60px 0 0 0;}
.menu-elements > a{ color: white; }
.menu-elements > a:hover{ color:#e87524;}

.logo{padding: 10px 0 0 0; text-align:center; margin:auto;}

.split{width: 3px;background: white;height: 28px; font-size: 32px; margin: 60px 0 0 0; text-align:center;}

.leftalign{text-align:left}
.rightalign{text-align:right;}
```

The problem I'm having is with the way my menu actually looks.

[This is with the rightalign and leftalign classes included.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XhuO.jpg)

[And this is without them included.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlxkJ.jpg)

I want the menu to be:

1: With the Logo dead center, hence why I've made the navigation into separate div's.

2: The links should take up an even amount of space each, however the way I've coded this makes the Testimonials link take up way more space that the other links, as it is longer which makes it look out of place and closer to the Logo. I tried fixing this by using the text-align style to align both inner links closer to the logo. But it still doesn't look right.

I'm wondering if anyone can think of any other ways I can try? Perhaps making the actual font stretch the letters to meet the edge of the div's or a certain percentage of the div by assigning more space in between the letters? I'll take any advice at this point.

If this isn't necessarily a programming question please point me in the right direction. I am looking for answers as to what I could try in code or in external reading: ie: "Look this up it might help" or "Here try this code it should correct them".

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but your code examples solved a question that I had. So thanks!